# How do you customize Item forms NewForm, EditForm and DispForm.aspx in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I have been allocated a site in SharePoint Online (latest/greatest version), full privileges to my Site Collection ... and zero privileges outside of that site collection.

I have SharePoint Designer 2013.

Neither InfoPath or PowerApps are options for me.

Q: How can I customize the forms?  Simple things: like rearrange the order of some fields; hide other fields?

I looked [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121856/customise-newform-aspx-and-editform-aspx), but I don't see any options to visually edit a form using my current versions of either SharePoint Designer or SharePoint.  I'm guessing that both have changed since that answer was posted in 2014.

RELATED QUESTIONS:

Q: What tools are available to modify a "classic" (.aspx) SharePoint form? Again: InfoPath and PowerApps are not options.

Q: Are there any tutorials you can point me to that tell me enough about SharePoint aspx syntax that I can modify the forms in Notepad?  Without a visual designer, SPD 2013 is little better than notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange the order of fields by list settings-> change column ordering...it will re-order fields in forms...

You can also hide  column using list settings -  use below link
https://myclassbook.org/hide-column-fields-sharepoint-2013/

For any other customization, You can modify forms pages by add content editor webpart to all 3 forms and use jquery to do the customization. Below are steps for same

- Go to your list and open the
  http://yourserver/Lists/yourlist/Forms/NewForm.aspx
- Open the new form without any parameter.
- From Site Actions Edit Page Add Content Editor web part
- Add required javascript

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: It *does* help!  Thank you!